# does postgresql has built in open metrics?

Tags: postgresql, devops, prometheus

Does anyone know whether PostgreSQL has built-in /metrics (or something like that)?
I've searched through the web and all I found was third party open source tools that send metrics to Prometheus

Thanks :)

Comment: What kind of metrics are you looking for? [This](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't have any `/metrics` endpoint. All sorts of metrics can be obtained through SQL queries from system tables.

[Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring) is the list of monitoring tools.

For Prometheus, there is a pretty good [exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter).